# Using errno with assertRaises in Unit Test

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm using assertRaises in my unit test to test the raising of specific exceptions.

```
assertRaises(IOError, testToRun, passedValues)
```

Though some of the exceptions I need to capture have specific error numbers (errno), so instead of collecting the base exception I'd like to capture the specific error number relating to that exception. Something like this, though it obviously doesn't work :)

```
assertRaises(IOError.errno(2), testToRun, passedValue)
```

To get around this when I want to capture specificly numbered exceptions I've been using:-

```
try:
    testToRun(passedValues)
except IOError, e:
    if e.errno == 2:
        pass
    else:
        raise
```

I'm sure it's not perfect but it works, but was wondering if it is possible to use assertRaises to do the same thing is a lot more compact way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Since 2.7 it's possible to use [`assertRaises`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) with a context manager:

```
with self.assertRaises(SomeException) as cm:
    do_something()

the_exception = cm.exception
self.assertEqual(the_exception.error_code, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not familiar with context manager but will read up on it.

Answer (score -1):

You could also create a new TestCase function using your current code:

```
def assertRaisesErrNo(self, exc, errno, f, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        self.assertRaises(exc, f, *args, **kwargs)
    except IOError, e:
        if e.errno == errno:
            pass
        else:
            raise

unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesErrNo = assertRaisesErrNo
```

Then use it like any other `assert` method:

```
class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_somthing(self):
        self.assertRaisesErrNo(IOError, 2, myfunction)
```

You could also turn this into a context manager fairly easily using [contextlib.contextmanager](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager)

Comment: Doesn't the assertRaises call handle the exception, so your special IOError code never gets run?  Have you tested this?